# How to count proportion of certain variable by group in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, count

I would like to calaculate proportion of apperances of value == 1 to sum of counts of apperances by group class.

Example data:

```
   value  class
     0  urban
     0  urban
     1 forest
     0 forest
     0   lake
     1    sea
     1    sea
     0    sea
```

Expected result:

```
  proportion_in_%  class
             0.0  urban
            50.0 forest
             0.0   lake
            66.6    sea
```

Code to make data:

```
data <- data.frame("value" = c(0,0,1,0,  0 , 1, 1, 0),
               "class" = c("urban", "urban", "forest", "forest", 
                           "lake", "sea", "sea", "sea"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
 data %>% group_by(class) %>% summarise(proportion = mean(value)*100) 
## A tibble: 4 x 2
#  class  proportion
#  <chr>       <dbl>
#1 forest       50  
#2 lake          0  
#3 sea          66.7
#4 urban         0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
data %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  summarize(Proportion_in_percent = (sum(value)*100)/n())
```

---

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  class  Proportion_in_percent
  <chr>                  <dbl>
1 forest                  50  
2 lake                     0  
3 sea                     66.7
4 urban                    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(cbind(Proption_in_percent = 100 *value) ~ class, data, FUN = mean )
```

-output

```
#    class Proption_in_percent
#1 forest            50.00000
#2   lake             0.00000
#3    sea            66.66667
#4  urban             0.00000
```